# Pairings in which 2 people are paired together

Tags: combinatorics

I was going through some combinatorics texts yesterday and was curious about a certain type of question. Given 2N students, I understand how to find the total number of possible pairings of those students. However, let's say two people want to be paired together. In how many of the total pairings of 2N people are those 2 together? How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Is this not just the number of pairings of $2(N-1)$ people?

Comment: Take the youngest person, whoever that may be.  Decide who that person's partner is.  Remove both from the available pool.  Now, from those who are left, take the youngest remaining person and choose their partner.  Repeat the process until none remain.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually quite easy if we assure ourselves that we can choose a specific student from the pool to start the first pair without altering the possible outcomes or their probabilities.

Let's say the students $X$ and $Y$ want to be together. We start by pairing up $X$ with another student. There are $2N - 1$ possible students to choose from (one of which is $Y$), each leading to the same number of *distinct* possible pairings. Thus the probability that $X$ will be paired with $Y$ is $\frac{1}{2N - 1}$, or the total number pairings where $X$ is paired with $Y$ is $\frac{(2 N - 1)!!}{2N - 1} = (2N - 3)!!$